# python file to dictionary

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have  a slightly different problem than the previous questions asked on this topic. Text file has the following contents

```
x1 x2 x3 gh3 tf2
0.1 0.7 0.8 0.9 8.9
y1 ft gt hh
2 4 7 8
.
.
.
```

I would like to add this to a dictionary , so has key: value x1:0.1 and so on.

this is what I have now and it doesnt really work for me

```
ned = {}
nel =[]
with open('test.dat', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        splitline= line.split()
        print(splitline)
        ned[int(splitline[0])] = ",".join(splitline[1:])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
temp_dict = dict()
with open("test.dat", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i in range(0, len(lines), 2):
        keys = lines[i].split()
        vals = lines[i + 1].split()
        temp_dict.update(key: val for key, val in zip(keys, vals))
```

Answer (score 0):

With `str.split()` and `zip` functions:

```
with open('test.dat', 'r') as f:
    d = {}
    for i,l in enumerate(f.read().splitlines()):
        if not i % 2:
            keys = l.split()
        else:
            d.update(zip(keys, l.split()))

print(d)
```

The output:

```
{'x1': '0.1', 'y1': '2', 'tf2': '8.9', 'ft': '4', 'x3': '0.8', 'gh3': '0.9', 'hh': '8', 'x2': '0.7', 'gt': '7'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
data = [i.strip('\n').split() for i in open('filename.txt')]
new_data = [{b[i]:b[i+1] for i in range(0, len(b), 2)} for b in zip(*data)]
final_dict = {}
for i in new_data:
   final_dict.update(i)
```

Output:

```
{'x1': '0.1', 'ft': '4', 'gt': '7', 'gh3': '0.9', 'y1': '2', 'hh': '8', 'x2': '0.7', 'x3': '0.8',...}
```

Comment: This is the most pythonic answer, but also imho the least readable. It depends on what you prefer I guess ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
lines_read = []
with open("test.dat", "r") as f:
    lines_read = f.readlines()

key_line = []
value_line = []
out_dict = {}
for i, line in enumerate(lines_read):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        key_line = line.strip().split()
    else:
        value_line = line.strip().split()
        out_dict.update(dict(zip(key_line, value_line)))
```

For conciseness, and if you do not care so much about writing explicit code you could do without the list initializations:

```
with open("test.dat", "r") as f:
    lines_read = f.readlines()

out_dict = {}
for i, line in enumerate(lines_read):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        key_line = line.strip().split()
    else:
        value_line = line.strip().split()
        out_dict.update(dict(zip(key_line, value_line)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following reads your file in two lines at a time and uses a dictionary comprehension to create a per 2-row dictionary to update `my_dict` with:

```
my_dict = {}

with open('test.dat') as f_input:
    for l1, l2 in zip(*[iter(f_input)] * 2):
        my_dict.update({k: v for k, v in zip(l1.split(), l2.split())})

print(my_dict)
```

Giving you:

```
{'gt': '7', 'ft': '4', 'gh3': '0.9', 'y1': '2', 'hh': '8', 'x2': '0.7', 'x3': '0.8', 'x1': '0.1', 'tf2': '8.9'}
```

To convert all the values to floats, change the update to:

```
my_dict.update({k: float(v) for k, v in zip(l1.split(), l2.split())})
```

Giving you:

```
{'gh3': 0.9, 'tf2': 8.9, 'x3': 0.8, 'gt': 7.0, 'y1': 2.0, 'x1': 0.1, 'ft': 4.0, 'hh': 8.0, 'x2': 0.7}
```